# Quitar una parte de todas las entradas de una columna tipo string en python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Tengo un dataset, df, similar a este:

```
| Año            |Peru  |Colombia | Brasil   | Ecuador|
--------------------------------------------------------
|precio_año_2000 |2     |5         |5         |6      |
|precio_año_2001 |2     |1         |6         |3      |
|precio_año_2002 |1     |1         |0         |6      | 
|precio_año_2003 |9     |4         |5         |9      | 
|precio_año_2004 |8     |7         |2         |8      |
```

Y necesito eliminar una parte del string de la primera columna

```
| Año            |Peru  |Colombia | Brasil   | Ecuador|
--------------------------------------------------------
|2000            |2     |5         |5         |6      |
|2001            |2     |1         |6         |3      |
|2002            |1     |1         |0         |6      | 
|2003            |9     |4         |5         |9      | 
|2004            |8     |7         |2         |8      |
```

Tienen alguna idea de cómo puedo hacerlo? Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda...

Comment: `df.Año.str.slice(-4)`

Comment: funcionará siempre y cuando no contenga espacios al final de cada cadena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando una columna contiene cadenas sobre las que quieras realizar operaciones (pasar a mayúsculas/minúsculas, eliminar espacios finales, obtener una rodaja, partirlas, etc.) puedes acceder a un "pseudoatributo" de esa columna llamado `.str` que te proporciona [muchas funciones](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#method-summary) *vectorizadas* (es decir, que operan sobre todos los elementos de la columna en una sola llamada).

Por ejemplo, dado tu dataframe de entrada, la siguiente operación (que te sugería en un comentario) obtendría las últimas cuatro letras de las entradas de la columna "Año":

```py
df.Año.str.slice(-4)
```

En tu caso producirá esta serie:

```
0    2000
1    2001
2    2002
3    2003
4    2004
```

Naturalmente puedes reasignar ese resultado a `df.Año`.

Si la cadena tiene un formato más variable (no siempre los últimos 4 caracteres son el año) puedes usar también `.str.split()` que divide la cadena por el caracter que le pidas (ej: "_" en este caso). El resultado es una lista que queda almacenada en cada celda, pero que podemos a su vez procesar mediante otr `.str.get()` para tomar uno de sus elementos, por ejemplo el último:

```
df.Año.str.split("_").str.get(-1)
```

Quizás también quieras asegurarte de que el resultado no contenga espacios por delante o por detrás. Basta añadir un `.str.strip()` adicional:

```
df.Año.str.split("_").str.get(-1).str.strip()
```

### Ampliación

La máxima generalidad te la dan las expresiones regulares. En este caso podemos usar la expresión regular `\d{4}` para encontrar una secuencia de 4 dígitos, en cualquier lugar de la cadena. Para buscar resultados usaríamos  `.str.findall()` que retorna para cada celda una lista con todos los resultados hallados. En tu dataframe de ejemplo la lista tendrá un solo resultado por celda (pues hay solo una secuencia de 4 dígitos en cada celda), por lo que podemos usar `.str.get(0)` para quedarnos con él. Es decir:

```
df.Año.str.findall(r"\d{4}").str.get(0)
```

Demo sobre un dataframe más complejo en el que el año aparece en cualquier lugar de la cadena bajo diferentes formatos:

|  | Año | Peru | Colombia | Brasil | Ecuador |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | precio_año_2000 | 2 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | precio_2001 | 2 | 1 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | precio de 2002 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 |
| 3 | precio-2003 | 9 | 4 | 5 | 9 |
| 4 | 2004_precio | 8 | 7 | 2 | 8 |

```
>>> df.Año.str.findall(r"\d{4}").str.get(0)
0    2000
1    2001
2    2002
3    2003
4    2004
```